# Endomorphism ring is isomorphic to group algebra.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C}(G))$ be the regular representation. $\mathbb{C}[G]$ denotes the group ring. Define 
$$
\operatorname{End}_{G}(\mathbb{C}(G)) = \left\{ \phi : \mathbb{C}(G) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}(G)  \mid \phi \circ \rho_{g} = \rho_{g} \circ \phi , \forall g \in G\right\}.
$$

This is a ring under $(+, \circ)$. Show that $\operatorname{End}_{G}(\mathbb{C}[G]) \cong \mathbb{C}[G]$. The hint is that $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_{G}(\mathbb{C}[G])$ is completely determined by $\phi(1)$, but I am not sure why that is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\phi(g) =\phi(g\cdot 1)=\phi(\rho_g(1))=\rho_g(\phi(1))=g\cdot\phi(1)$.

Comment: Sure, so then would the isomorphism be $\psi : End_{G}(V) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[G]$ be $\psi(\phi) = \phi(1)$? If so, how do I show that it is bijective? I am thinking that $End_{G}(\mathbb{C}[G])$ has dimension $|G|$ as a vector space, and is injective, since it is completely determined by $\phi(1)$, and so it must be surjective because $\psi$ is a map between finite dimensional vector spaces. How do I show that $\psi ( \phi_{1} \circ \phi_{2} ) = \phi_{1}(1) \cdot \phi_{2}(1)$?

Comment: It might be easier to directly write down the inverse to $\psi$, since ring morphisms $\mathbb{C}[G] \to R$ are in bijection with group morphisms $G \to R^{\times}$. In this case, $R = End_{G}(\mathbb{C}[G])$, and it seems to me that there is a nice map $G \to R^{\times}$ given by sending $g$ to right-multiplication by $g$. (Maybe I have made some mistake though - in particular, might be left-multiplication by $g$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that such a $\phi$ is determined by $\phi(1)$ following Berci's comment. The map

$$
 \operatorname{ev}_1 : \operatorname{End}_G(\mathbb{C}[G]) \to \mathbb{C}[G] \ : \ \phi \mapsto \phi(1)
$$

is hence injective. But $\operatorname{ev}_1$ is clearly an additive morphism, and then suppose that $\phi_i(1) = \sum_{g \in G} a^{(i)}_g g = \sum_{g \in G} a^{(i)}_g \rho_g(1)$, then

\begin{align*}
\phi_1(\phi_2(1)) & = \phi_1\left(\sum_{g \in G} a^{(2)}_g  \rho_g(1)\right) \\
& = \sum_{g \in G} a^{(2)}_g \phi_1(\rho_g(1)) \\
& = \sum_{g \in G} a^{(2)}_g \rho_g(\phi_1(1)) \\
& = \sum_{g \in G} a^{(2)}_g \rho_g\left( \sum_{h \in G} a^{(1)}_h \rho_h(1) \right) \\
& = \sum_{g \in G, h \in G} a_g^{(2)}a_h^{(1)} gh \\
& = \left( \sum_{g \in G} a^{(2)}_g g  \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{h \in G} a^{(1)}_h h  \right)  \\
& = \phi_2(1) \cdot \phi_1(1)
\end{align*}

and so $\operatorname{ev}_1$ is an injective ring anti-homomorphism from $\operatorname{End}_G\left(\mathbb{C}[G] \right)$ to $\mathbb{C}[G]$. But $\operatorname{ev}_1$ is certainly surjective since given $x = \sum_{g \in G} \alpha_g g \in \mathbb{C}[G]$ then $\psi_x : \mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}[G]$ sending $h$ to $hx = \sum_{g \in G} \alpha_g hg$ is an element of $\operatorname{End}_G(\mathbb{C}[G])$ such that $\operatorname{ev}_1(\psi_x) = x$. It follows that as rings $\operatorname{End}_G(\mathbb{C}[G]) \cong \mathbb{C}[G]^{\operatorname{op}}$.

Comment: I did the same calculation and got the same result. So this means that $End_{G}(\mathbb{C}[G]) \cong \mathbb{C}[G]^{op}$, but not $End_{G}(\mathbb{C}[G]) \cong \mathbb{C}[G]$, right, because multiplication is not commutative in the group algebra?

Comment: Yes that is correct.